# How to return ModelState with Forbidden status web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, modelstate, modelstatedictionary

We can return `ModelState` with `BadRequest` from web api in following way:

```
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

It provides following output:

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "property": [
            "error"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I return the same output with `Forbidden` status?

I tried following method:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ModelState);
```

But it returns:

```
{
    "property": {
        "_errors": [
            {
                "<Exception>k__BackingField": null,
                "<ErrorMessage>k__BackingField": "error"
            }
        ],
        "<Value>k__BackingField": null
    }
}
```

Json serializing `ModelSate` is also not returning the same thing. How can I use the serialization method used by `BadRequest()` method for `ModelState` with other status codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output by using the `ExecuteAsync` method of `InvalidModelStateResult` (return type of `BadRequest()` method of `ApiController`) which actually serializes the `ModelState`.

So the idea is to create a new class which extends `InvalidModelStateResult` and override `ExecuteAsync` method to change the status code.

```
public class ModelStateResult : InvalidModelStateResult
{
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _status;

    public ModelStateResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, ApiController controller, HttpStatusCode status) : base(modelState, controller)
    {
        _status = status;
    }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken).Result;
        response.StatusCode = _status;
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
return new ModelStateResult(ModelState, this, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);    //this refers to ApiController here
```

I think this is just a work around, hope someone posts a better way to achieve it.

**EDIT:**

Without using `InvalidModelStateResult`:

```
public class ModelStateResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public HttpStatusCode Status { get; }
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; }
    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; }

    public ModelStateResult(HttpStatusCode status, ModelStateDictionary modelState, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Status = status;
        ModelState = modelState;
        Request = request;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(Status, ModelState);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```